# VB.NET DataSet Function

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I'm trying to see if there's a better way to use a function that returns a DataSet to fill a combo box, or a cleaner code, faster way, etc.

Function:

```
    Public Function FillDataSet(ByVal dataSet As DataSet, ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet
      Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=database; User ID=user;Password=password;")
         Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter() With {.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)}
            adapter.Fill(DataSet)
         End Using
         Return DataSet
      End Using
    End Function
```

Calling Sub:

```
    Private Sub fillComboBox()
      comboBox.Items.Clear()
      Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
      myDataSet = FillDataSet(myDataSet , "SELECT rows FROM table")
      If myDataSet .Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row As DataRow In myDataSet .Tables(0).Rows
          comboBox.Items.Add(row(0))
        Next row
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
      Else
        MsgBox("Empty table.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Empty Table...")
      End If
      myDataSet .Dispose()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the for each loop with `comboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)` then assign which column to dispaly with its column name `comboBox.DisplayMember = "ColumnName"` and value member for catching its `SelectedValue`

```
comboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
comboBox.DisplayMember = "ColumnName"
comboBox.ValueMember = "ColumnName"
```